# Integer to IV type conversion

Tags: haskell, encryption, cryptography

I am using AES256 from [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/src/Crypto-Cipher-AES.html) library and types from [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-cipher-types-0.0.9/docs/src/Crypto-Cipher-Types.html) library. here `ctrCombine` function takes `IV` (Initialisation Vector) in `IV cipher` type.

Instead of generating random `IV` from `makeIV` function, I want to generate it from some Integers that I already have.

1. Is it possible to convert any Integer to  'IV cipher' type?
2. If it is possible how can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at `nullIV` and `ivAdd` from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptocipher-0.6.2/docs/Crypto-Cipher.html#g:3) - it looks like you could just do something like `ivAdd ivNull x`, although whether that'd have the effect you're after I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

`makeIV` doesn't generate a random IV as you implied. It is exactly the function you want. Just serialize your integer to a bytestring of sufficient length then call makeIV on that bytestring:

```
makeIV $ runPut (putWord64be (fromIntegral i) >>putWord64be (fromIntegral (i `shiftR` 64)))
```

where the put operations are from the `cereal` package.  You could use `binary` instead of `cereal` but then you'd have to make sure you get a strict bytestring.

EDIT: A more complete example:

```hs
import Data.Binary.Put
import Crypto.Cipher.Types
import Crypto.Cipher.AES (AES256)
import Data.ByteArray (unpack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import Data.Bits (shiftR)

example :: Integer -> IV AES256
example i =
  maybe (error "foo") id $
  -- ^^ makeIV returns a `Maybe` (Nothing for IVs of incorrect size
  makeIV $ LBS.toStrict $
  --      ^^ makeIV requires strict bytestrings
     runPut (putWord64be (fromIntegral i) >>
             putWord64be (fromIntegral (i `shiftR` 64)))
  -- ^^ Construct your IV bytestring however you'd like

main = do print $ unpack (example 0)
          print $ unpack (example 1)
          print $ unpack (example (2^63))
          print $ unpack (example (2^65))
          print $ unpack (example (2^112))
          print $ unpack (example (2^120))
```

Notice that this DOES NOT use crypto-cipher-types since that is sort of parallel to and separate from cryptonite.  You should use the IV type from cryptonite instead (see Cryptonite's `Crypto.Cipher.Types` modules).

Comment: Except the OP should be aware that using a non random IV is a security flaw and whatever reason they have to build it from integers is definitely not a good enough reason.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark That's only true for CBC mode (and a few obscure related ones), not for most other cipher modes (you can also mess up CTR counter mode construction, of course).

Comment: Thomas, could you indicate the counter block that is generated with your code? It seems that the library requires the full 16 bytes as IV...

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking but I did clumsily not cast my input integer as I should have - see the `fromIntegral` edit.  Once I get a moment I'll edit with a full (runnable) example.

Comment: is it fine to use predictable (increment by 1 each time) IV in AES256 CTR mode?, If we use random how can we guarantee that will be not repeat after certain messages?

Comment: @MaheshUligade No it is not fine.  If you are developing for a production system I strongly suggest you find a crypto engineer.  In short, AES256 CTR will internally use all IVs from the one provided upwards as needed (so, up to iv + plaintext / blockSize).  You'd need to increment your IV by at least that much to maintain confidentiality.

Comment: @MaheshUligade If you use random IVs there is never a guarantee no IV will repeat.  You can model the issue as a statistical "balls and bins" problem to determine the probability.  I suggest you put conservative limits on how much data and how many encryptions are allowed to occur any time you use random IVs.  I believe IETF RFCs on IPSec have useful/reasonable limits if you are looking for motivation.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson  How much should be the min size of random IV, so it won't repeat soon

Comment: You don't get to choose the size of the IV - that is dictated by the cipher and the mode.